# Does my following hypothesis make any sense?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

[image]Only three entities exist: Everything, Nothing, and Information.
Reasoning: For any Thing to exists there must also be something else that's not that Thing, otherwise the Thing wouldn't or couldn't be defined. The something else must be Nothing, otherwise it would be Everything.
If two entities exist, there must be some relationship between them otherwise they might coincide. The third entity is Information relating Everything and Nothing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105215/discussion-on-question-by-djacob7-does-my-following-hypothesis-make-any-sense).

Answer (score -1):

Sure.

It's like saying that reality's made out of [turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down), or [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory), or whatever – you can assert it [without error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency).  But until your theory is developed enough to create [falsifiable predictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability), it doesn't really [mean anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) yet.

As far as foundational theories go, it's not a bad start: you're asserting two different sorts of representations ("*Everything*" and "*Nothing*"), then asserting that they're described by information.  That's a lot like saying the universe is made out of 0's and 1's in a binary data structure.